# qt quick material style controls

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm trying to design a qt quick application using qml. From what I gather in the documentation of qt is that these controls have support for styling automatically (e.g. there's a material light/material dark themes.

However, when I tried to apply it to the tabview control I can't get the styling to be applied. I can make a propery binding ala `Rectangle { color: Material.color(Material.Red)}` This works well for looking up any of the predefined colors, however I don't seem to be able to access attached (inherited) properties like `Material.background`

How can I best apply theming to controls that don't support it? It doesn't look like it's possible to property binding to an attached property- or at least qt/qml seems to get confused because `Material.` is also considered the namespace.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow;
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")    
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Purple


    TabView {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        tabPosition: Qt.BottomEdge
        Material.theme: Material.Dark
        Material.accent: Material.Purple

        Tab {
            title: "Red"
            Material.theme: Material.Dark
            Material.accent: Material.Purple
        }
        Tab {
            title: "Blue"
            Rectangle { color: "blue" }
        }
        Tab {
            title: "Green"
            Material.theme: Material.Dark
            Material.accent: Material.Purple
        }

        style: TabViewStyle {
            frameOverlap: 1
            tab: Rectangle {
                color: styleData.selected ? "steelblue" :"lightsteelblue"
                border.color:  "steelblue"
                implicitWidth: Math.max(text.width + 4, 80)
                implicitHeight: 20
                radius: 2
                Text {
                    id: text
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: styleData.title
                    color: styleData.selected ? "white" : "black"
                }
            }
            frame: Item {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TabView` is from Controls 1. You should use `TabBar` and `TabButton`, as the Material style is only available with Qt Quick Controls 2:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html#type-comparison-table

Comment: Hmm but that would mean recreate all of the tab view logic yourself? That seems like an awful lot of work for a technology that has the intent of saving me to do work.

Comment: No, they are replacements. There's an example of how it's used here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html#details